# Provider call dispose with tab items in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I am using same provider and model for storing state for my API to order with different order status because only the order status is changing and I displayed them in separate screens in tab bar and called provider to fetch response on each tab switch but I'm facing error with dispose method and also data is inconsistent through out the tab view when switched frequently can anyone suggest the right way to solve this?

**This is my code for tab items**

```dart
                        OrderMainScreen(token: _token),
                        OrderStatusScreen(
                          token: _token,
                          orderStatus: "unpaid",
                        ),
                        OrderStatusScreen(
                          token: _token,
                          orderStatus: "processing",
                        ),
                        OrderStatusScreen(
                          token: _token,
                          orderStatus: "delivered",
                        ),
                      ]),
```

**This is the code where I fetch the order status**

```dart
class OrderStatusScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;
  final String orderStatus;

  OrderStatusScreen({this.token, this.orderStatus});

  _OrderStatusScreenState createState() => _OrderStatusScreenState();
}

class _OrderStatusScreenState extends State<OrderStatusScreen> {
  void initState() {
    if (mounted) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) {
        Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchUserOrderStatus(widget.token, status: widget.orderStatus);
      });
      super.initState();
    }
  }
```

I get this error when frequently switching between tabs

```
W/MediaPlayer-JNI(28753): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
E/flutter (28753): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (28753): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #0      State.context.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #1      State.context[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (28753): #2      _OrderStatusScreenState.initState.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:152:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:704:45)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:733:32)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #8      Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:530:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #9      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:312:16)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #16     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1186:23)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #17     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #18     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #19     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (28753): #20     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)[39;49m
E/flutter (28753):
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you show show the code that produces these errors

Comment: @TryHarder Thank you for the advise just edited my question can you please review it

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer but I still gonna point out the part which might be the reason you getting this error.

1. You don't have to check `if(mounted)` inside `initState` because initState will run when the widget tree is built, to make it simple, the moment you navigate to this page it will run `initState` first then only do the rest.
2. If you are using `Tab bar` with `Tab Bar View`, please refer this link https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs to understand how to work with Flutter tab bar.
3. If the `tab items` you are referring turns out to be Flutter `Tab Bar` then you must understand when ever you navigate through a tab bar, the old tab view will be dispose and the new tab bar view you are going to view will be build. This might be the reason you got this error.
4. Preferable for every tab bar view is a new stateful widget.